# Postgresql/openJPA (geronimo) Sequence Issue

Tags: postgresql, sequence, openjpa, geronimo

I am having a weird problem with a sequence. Im using postgresql 9 with geronimo 2.2. I have created the sequence `PLANTS_ID_SEQ` inside the db environment and when I try to create a new entity I get an error in my logs (which comes from postegresql) that the relation `PLANTS_ID_SEQ` exists. It seems that it tries to create the sequence that is already created. This is the code from the entity bean:

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator="PLANTS_SEQ",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE) @SequenceGenerator(name="PLANTS_SEQ", sequenceName="PLANTS_ID_SEQ",allocationSize=1) @Column(name = "ID") 
private Integer id;
```

Please notice that if I change the sequence name (`eg sequenceName="MY_SEQ"`)then the code runs correctly but it creates in postgresql (and obviously uses) the MY_SEQ sequence. If anyone has a clue about this case please share. 
Thanks George

Comment: You should report this as a bug, I think...

Answer (score 1):

If your table has a column of type SERIAL, then postgres will create the sequence for you and use it automatically on inserts.

The sequence it creates is named "tablename_id_seq"...

Probably you're trying to duplicate what postgres has already done, and create a duplicate sequence.

Comment: The problem is that jpa tries to create the sequence every time the server is restarted. probably, it ignores the existance of the sequence. Thus, the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: 
Should add in persistence.xml the following property:

```
property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(Sequences=false)"
```

this way, the MappingTool of openjpa will not try to create the sequence again.

Comment: I think you missed to also show us the property that should be added in persistence.xml

Comment: You are right, it was inside tag property and purged by the editor. I striped the tag and updated.